# Codelite IDE not opening on windows 10

Tags: c++, codelite

Installed the latest version of Code lite IDE-15.0.04.
Was working till yesterday but now not opening. No error or messages flashing. Simply not opening.
Tried troubleshooting as well.
OS - Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason that this happens is due to unclean shutdown and corrupted configuration files. To easiest solution is to delete the user settings folder.

Note that Uninstalling CodeLite does not help, since the user settings are kept.

So:

- Close CodeLite
- Delete the folder `%appdata%\CodeLite`
- Start CodeLite

This should do the trick